# Split String and store every splitted element into array

Tags: arrays, node.js, split

String is stored in a variable `str`  as below:

```
var str = {"data": ["$GPRP,1B2A956ABDF6,AC83F3D44470,-83,1EFF060001092002D9323D6A81154B1BB21D82FB817B1267D51CDD914EEBE7", "$GPRP,0D5B196F34D4,AC83F3D44470,-81,1EFF060001092000303D9AE7017A09C87A6A285EC9B8FA6E66C08F7D1E30FA", "$GPRP,75560B6500E2,AC83F3D44470,-100,02011A0AFF4C0010051B1CEA7019"]};
```

Now i want to split this string and store it in an array.
I need Output like this,

```
var Array = [["1B2A956ABDF6","AC83F3D44470",-83],["0D5B196F34D4","AC83F3D44470",-81],["75560B6500E2","AC83F3D44470",-100]];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also what are the rules? I mean it seems you want 2nd, 3rd and 4th element from each string. Correct?

Comment: Yes i want 2nd, 3rd and 4th elemet from each string @Molda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to parse your string and once it's parsed this is how you do it.

```
let strArray = []
for (let i=0; i<str.data.length; i++) {
    let newStr = str.data[i].split(",").slice(1, 4)
    strArray.push(newStr)
}

console.log(strArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

The str that you are having is a [JSON](https://www.json.org/).

You can convert it into object by using

```
var parsedStr = JSON.parse(str)
```

and then access the data array from it using

```
var Array = parsedStr.data
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the string first:

```
var str = '{"data": ["$GPRP,1B2A956ABDF6,AC83F3D44470,-83,1EFF060001092002D9323D6A81154B1BB21D82FB817B1267D51CDD914EEBE7", "$GPRP,0D5B196F34D4,AC83F3D44470,-81,1EFF060001092000303D9AE7017A09C87A6A285EC9B8FA6E66C08F7D1E30FA", "$GPRP,75560B6500E2,AC83F3D44470,-100,02011A0AFF4C0010051B1CEA7019"]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Iterate through the `obj.data` array:

```
var arr = [];
obj.data.forEach(function(item){
    var tmp = item.split(',');
    arr.push(tmp.slice(1, 4));
});
console.log(arr);
```

See jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pjxLu0c3/

Comment: For `var str = {"data": ["$GPRP,1B2A956ABDF6,AC83F3D44470,-83,1EFF060001092002D9323D6A81154B1BB21D82FB817B1267D51CDD914EEBE7", "$GPRP,0D5B196F34D4,AC83F3D44470,-81,1EFF060001092000303D9AE7017A09C87A6A285EC9B8FA6E66C08F7D1E30FA", "$GPRP,75560B6500E2,AC83F3D44470,-100,02011A0AFF4C0010051B1CEA7019"]};` no need to parse string.

Comment: Yes now that you **removed the quotes** surrounding the object **from your question**. Original question had the qoutes so the **parsing was needed**.

Comment: String in double quote shows me error, so i removed the quotes from string. But your solution works properly. Thank you so much for your support.